# Derivative of determinant of a matrix w.r.t a scalar

Tags: determinant, matrix-calculus

So as per the matrix cookbook,

$\frac{d |\textbf{A}|}{d \alpha} = |\textbf{A}| \operatorname{Tr}(\textbf{A}^{-1} \frac{d \textbf{A}}{d \alpha})$

where $\textbf{A}$ is a matrix and $\alpha$ is a scalar.

and

$\frac{d |\textbf{A}|}{d \textbf{A}} = |\textbf{A}| (\textbf{A}^{-1})^{T}$

but $\frac{d |\textbf{A}|}{d \alpha}$ can be written as $\frac{d |\textbf{A}|}{d \textbf{A}}.\frac{d \textbf{A}}{d \alpha} = |\textbf{A}| (\textbf{A}^{-1})^{T} \frac{d \textbf{A}}{d \alpha}$ as per the chain rule.

Clearly I have misunderstood something. Why is the result I get with the chain rule not correct?

Is it wrong to apply the chain rule here?

Comment: Instead of a dot product, you must use a double-dot product (aka matrix inner product) in the chain rule
$$\large{
\def\LR#1{\left( #1 \right)}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial#2}}
\grad{\,\det A}{\alpha} = \LR{\grad{\,\det A}A}:\grad{A}{\alpha}  \\
}$$

Comment: This is easier to understand if you write the indices of matrix.

Comment: @greg Just to confirm, the matrix inner product is the same as this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product ?

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of the mapping $B \mapsto \det B$ is given by
$D \det(B)(H) = \det B \operatorname{tr} (B^{-1} H)$ (assuming that $B$ is invertible).

Hence the chain rule applied to $\det \circ A$ will give
$D (\det \circ A) (\alpha) (h) = D \det (A(\alpha)) (D A(\alpha) h) = \det(A(\alpha)) \operatorname{tr} (A(\alpha)^{-1}D A(\alpha) h)$, which is what you have above.